# Hide a dialog through a factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-factory

I am using angular material.

I created a factory to display a loading modal.

I can display it, but I can't dismiss it.

Could you tell me why, or tell me how to do it ?

Here is my factory :

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('loveProjectApp')
    .factory('ProgressFactory', ProgressFactory);

ProgressFactory.$inject = ['$mdDialog'];

/* @ngInject */
function ProgressFactory($mdDialog) {
    var service = {
        show: show,
        cancel: cancel
    };
    return service;

    ////////////////

    function show() {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'miscellaneous/progress/progress.dialog.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose: false,
            fullscreen: false
        });
    }

    function cancel() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    }
}
})();
```

And I call it like this :

```
        function logout() {
        ProgressFactory.show();
        authFactory.logout().then(function() {
            ToastFactory.successToast('SUCCESSES.DISCONNECTED');
            $state.reload();
            ProgressFactory.cancel();
        });
```

So the loader is shown, but isn't dismissed.

Comment: it's `$mdDialog.cancel();` or `$mdDialog.hide();` I mean try both

Comment: I tried both, neither work ... And `.hide()` works too btw, it resolves the promise instead of rejecting it

Comment: quick question what `$state.reload();` is doing here?

Comment: That doesn't help me, but when I (dis)connect an user, I reload the state to refresh the page he's on, so that I can hide some information that he can not see if he's logged out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOUND IT !**

My server is running on the same machine that my application uses.

I was calling `$mdDialog.cancel();` too fast visibly, so I added a 1s timeout in the factory, and now the dialog dismisses correctly.

It now works like a charm, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/grxXwY?editors=1010) of your code and the dialog does close. I have used a $timeout to replicate your `authFactory.logout()` call.

This makes me think that

- The `.then` callback function is not being called, or
- Something is happening before `ProgressFactory.cancel();` is called that prevents it from being executed

JS

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, ProgressFactory) {
  $scope.logout = function () {
      ProgressFactory.show();
      $timeout(function () {
        ProgressFactory.cancel();
      }, 2000);
    }
})
```

Comment: Well I tried with a timeout and it doesn't work either. I assume it comes from a bad thing I did, except that I can't find what ... Anyway if it works for you, it can work for me, I'll look for the issue and keep the topic updated, thank you !